# Looping over a data frame and adding a new column in R with certain logic

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, iteration

I have a data frame which contains information about sales branches, customers and sales.

```
branch <- c("Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","Chicago","LA","LA","LA","LA","LA","LA","LA","Tampa","Tampa","Tampa","Tampa","Tampa","Tampa","Tampa","Tampa")

customer <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)

sales <- c(33816,24534,47735,1467,39389,30659,21074,20195,45165,37606,38967,41681,47465,3061,23412,22993,34738,19408,11637,36234,23809)


data   <- data.frame(branch, customer, sales)
```

What I need to accomplish is to iterate over each branch, take each customer in the branch and divide the sales for that customer by the total of the branch. I need to do it to find out how much each customer is contributing towards the total sales of the corresponding branch. E.g. for customer 1 I would like to divide 33816/177600 and store this value in a new column. (177600 is the total of chicago branch)

I have tried to write a function to iterate over each row in a for loop but I am not sure how to do it at a branch level. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:git]?

Comment: For future reference, `customer <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21)` can be expressed as `customer <- 1:21`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider base R's `ave` for new column of inline aggregate which also considers same customer with multiple records within the same branch:

```
data$customer_contribution <- ave(data$sales, data$customer, FUN=sum) / 
                              ave(data$sales, data$branch, FUN=sum)

data
#     branch customer sales customer_contribution
# 1  Chicago        1 33816           0.190405405
# 2  Chicago        2 24534           0.138141892
# 3  Chicago        3 47735           0.268778153
# 4  Chicago        4  1467           0.008260135
# 5  Chicago        5 39389           0.221784910
# 6  Chicago        6 30659           0.172629505
# 7       LA        7 21074           0.083576241
# 8       LA        8 20195           0.080090263
# 9       LA        9 45165           0.179117441
# 10      LA       10 37606           0.149139610
# 11      LA       11 38967           0.154537126
# 12      LA       12 41681           0.165300433
# 13      LA       13 47465           0.188238887
# 14   Tampa       14  3061           0.017462291
# 15   Tampa       15 23412           0.133560003
# 16   Tampa       16 22993           0.131169705
# 17   Tampa       17 34738           0.198172193
# 18   Tampa       18 19408           0.110718116
# 19   Tampa       19 11637           0.066386372
# 20   Tampa       20 36234           0.206706524
# 21   Tampa       21 23809           0.135824795
```

Or less wordy:

```
data$customer_contribution <- with(data, ave(sales, customer, FUN=sum) / 
                                         ave(sales, branch, FUN=sum))
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::mutate` to calculate fractional sales of total by `branch`.

```
library(dplyr);
library(magrittr);
data %>%
    group_by(branch) %>%
    mutate(sales.norm = sales / sum(sales))    
## A tibble: 21 x 4
## Groups:   branch [3]
#   branch  customer  sales sales.norm
#   <fct>      <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 Chicago       1. 33816.    0.190
# 2 Chicago       2. 24534.    0.138
# 3 Chicago       3. 47735.    0.269
# 4 Chicago       4.  1467.    0.00826
# 5 Chicago       5. 39389.    0.222
# 6 Chicago       6. 30659.    0.173
# 7 LA            7. 21074.    0.0836
# 8 LA            8. 20195.    0.0801
# 9 LA            9. 45165.    0.179
#10 LA           10. 37606.    0.149
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy! I knew group_by and mutate but I did not know group_by could be used like this. thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome @RaviDawar; please consider closing this question by setting the check mark next to an answer.